# update query inside view in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> create view incremented_salary as
    -> update employee set salary=salary*1.1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'update employee set salary=salary*1.1' at line 2
```

can we put update query inside view? If yes then please tell me why I'm getting above error.I want to increment the salary and display it using view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you

```
create view incremented_salary as
  select salary*1.1 from wahtevertable
```

Views do not modify the values of tables.

They give you a new View on them - f.e. joining multiple tables, aggregating and maybe recalculate some values based on tablevalues.

If what you tried would work, everytime you`d viewed the data, it would increase in value.